# Dynamically how to generated multiple table as a Json Data requirement in itextpdf

Tags: kotlin, itext, pdfptable

Generated multiple table in itextpdf. below given Json Format:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "challan": [
        {
            "Cmp_Name": "ABC",
            "Partyid": "18",
            "ChallanNo": "-",
            "PartyName": "PURCHASE MH",
            "FirmName": "PURCHASE MH",
            "ChallanDate": "-",
            "ChallanAmount": "0.0",
            "RecieveDate": "2019-03-15 00:00:00",
            "RecieveAmount": "4000.0",
            "DiscountAmount": "0.0",
            "TDSAmount": "0.0",
            "Bank": "AXIS BANK",
            "ChequeNo": null,
            "ChequeDate": null
        },
        {
            "Cmp_Name": "ABC",
            "Partyid": "17",
            "ChallanNo": "20",
            "PartyName": "PURCHASE GJ",
            "FirmName": "PURCHASE GJ",
            "ChallanDate": "3/11/2019",
            "ChallanAmount": "1391.0",
            "RecieveDate": "2019-03-15 00:00:00",
            "RecieveAmount": "1391.0",
            "DiscountAmount": "0.0",
            "TDSAmount": "0.0",
            "Bank": "AXIS BANK",
            "ChequeNo": "321456",
            "ChequeDate": "2019-03-15 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "Cmp_Name": "ABC",
            "Partyid": "17",
            "ChallanNo": "20",
            "PartyName": "Dharama",
            "FirmName": "Dharama",
            "ChallanDate": "3/11/2019",
            "ChallanAmount": "1391.0",
            "RecieveDate": "2019-03-15 00:00:00",
            "RecieveAmount": "1391.0",
            "DiscountAmount": "0.0",
            "TDSAmount": "0.0",
            "Bank": "AXIS BANK",
            "ChequeNo": "321456",
            "ChequeDate": "2019-03-15 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "Cmp_Name": "ABC",
            "Partyid": "17",
            "ChallanNo": "20",
            "PartyName": "Dharama",
            "FirmName": "Dharama",
            "ChallanDate": "3/11/2019",
            "ChallanAmount": "1391.0",
            "RecieveDate": "2019-03-15 00:00:00",
            "RecieveAmount": "1391.0",
            "DiscountAmount": "0.0",
            "TDSAmount": "0.0",
            "Bank": "AXIS BANK",
            "ChequeNo": "321456",
            "ChequeDate": "2019-03-15 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Above `Json` Format `PartyName` Key when `Partyname` same value `JsonObject` data show in one table after when `PartyName` Value Change all `JSONObject` data show in another table.

`PartyName` value same all `JsonObject` data show in one table and value change dynamically generated as depend on `PartyName` Value.

Above `JSON` Format two `PartyName` value different so, two table create in `itextPdf`. how to its create?

how to generated multiple table `itextpdf`?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196994/json-key-wise-data-separated-and-show-in-table

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842391/itext-pdf-one-table-depends-on-data-multiple-table-create-in-android

Comment: And another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835407/jsonsame-key-diffrent-value-how-to-show-in-tablelayout

Comment: And yet another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55830948/json-data-key-wise-data-display-in-tablelayout-and-textview